# How to create a new environment correctly - including using "pip install something"

Tags: pip, anaconda3

Can anybody recommend how to do the following smartest:

- Make a new environment called "wells"
- in addition to anaconda packages like matplotlib, numphy, pandas ++,
- install packages like

  - "pip install lasio", "pip install dlisio", ..

Tried cloning anaconda, but after 30+ minutes I stopped it.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of speed, I recommend beginning with [Miniconda3](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and immediately after installing, running these commands to ensure that all packages are installed from [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) wherever possible:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

To create the environment, I recommend using an [environment file](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually). Create a text file named `environment.yml`, where you can specify packages which are available via conda on e.g. [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) (numpy, matplotlib, pandas in this case) as well as a separate list for packages available via pip on e.g. [PyPI](https://pypi.org/): lasio, dlisio in this case.

Example `environment.yml` file:

```
name: examplename
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - pip:
    - lasio
    - dlisio
```

Then you can create the environment `wells` using this command:

```
conda env create -n wells -f environment.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, it uses Python3.x. I ran this to verify it would be faster than the 30+ minutes you experienced.  It took less than 4 minutes.  So hopefully this will work for you.

```
# Create a work directory
mkdir wells
cd wells

# Create a virual environement named 'wells'
python3 -m venv wells
# Start the virual environment
source wells/bin/activate
# Update the basic virtual environment tools
pip install -U pip setuptools

# Create a requirements.txt with all the packages to install
echo matplotlib >>requirements.txt
echo numpy >> requirements.txt
echo pandas >> requirements.txt 
echo lasio >> requirements.txt 
echo dlisio >> requirements.txt

# Install the packages
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When done working with the virtual environment, deactivate it with:

```
deactivate
```

Additionally, if using a Conda enviroment instead of a `Python -m venv` virtual env refer to these links for steps:
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

Also, it will be faster with fewer unneeded pkgs to use Miniconda instead of full Anaconda.

Comment: Hi I plan to base this on conda,  Assuming "conda create wells" do the same as your "mkdir wells - cd wells - python3 -m venv wells - ++" ...?

Comment: Hi, I don't have the experience with conda, but a quick look at https://github.com/conda/conda, it looks like you should replace the python virtual-env (venv) cmds, with conda specific cmds. The `pip install` should be replaced with conda's install syntax. If you wanted to try and update this post with your results that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. => Learned something new about pip :-). I stick to using conda though, I create new environments when adding packages only available from pip (conda's pip). Do not clone the anaconda "base" but only install strictly needed packages in new environments. (PS! I'm not an expert here ... a retired geo-modeller).